# aix shell trouble getting value returned from function

Tags: shell, unix, aix

In the script below RES always returns to nothing; Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks in advance.

```
#!/bin/sh
set -x
chk_for() {
    RES=0
    RES= $(head -1 $1 | fgrep -c "Formula" >&2) 
    echo "@@@@" || $RES
    return $RES
    }

for X in /home/wstandke/webcatstats/rep/AnalysisWork/*; do
    chk_for "$X" 

    if [$? == 1]
        then 
           echo "1st line is heading"
            file=$(basename $X)
            echo "fullname=" || $X
            echo "filename=" || $file
           mv $X /tmp/$file
            sed 1d /tmp/$file > $X
            rm /tmp/$file
    fi
done
cat /home/wstandke/webcatstats/rep/AnalysisWork/*  >/tmp/Analysis.report
```

Comment: aix `/#!/bin/sh` is almost certainly the original Bourne Shell, which doesn't support `$(cmd_substitution)`. Try removing space, per below AND using `backtics` instead. Also best to understand what is being processed, turn on shell trace features `set -vx` to see variable expansions as they happing. Good luck.

Comment: @shelter No... probably not.  /bin/sh is very often ksh.  /bin/bsh (as I recall) is the Bourne Shell.  As I recall, there is an option somewhere to set it.  I believe one option is even to set it to ksh93.

Answer (score 2):

You redirect the output of `fgrep` to `stderr`, thus not assigning any value to `RES`.

Also, not sure if that is *the* problem, but there is a blank after `RES=` which might assign blank to `RES`.

Try changing the line in question to:

```
RES=$(head -1 $1 | fgrep -c "Formula")
```

Comment: +1 for the space between the equal sign and the value to be assigned.